I set in-app products：local price ， but purchase a different price in googleplay
in-app products：I set local prices for four regions currency
productid：google_usd_1.00
default price：16000IDR
local price:ID 16000IDR; MY 5.13MYR; HK 7.83HKD; US 1.00USD;
However, when I tested the payment using my HK account, the price of the product shown is 7.75HKD and will change over time.
Under normal circumstances, should the price of this item be the 7.83HKD I set? the same price as the listed local price.
1.here is the setting picture

2.here is the purchase picture

Is there something wrong here?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It is the exchange rate, when exchange rate differ the local pricing will differ. and there is also country-specific pricing patterns, this means the price will increase or decrease in a specific pattern depending on currency, for USD its 1 dollar increments on 0.99, so it is (0.99, 1.99, 2.99, etc.)

see this link to see the changing exchange rate for your specific case.
